# Pre-flight OPTIONS request delays my DELETE

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, redux, cors

I am `delete`ing an object then immediately retrieving a list of available objects, and am hitting a race-esk problem.

`DELETE` requests are subject to a [CORS Pre-Flight `OPTIONS` request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests), while the `GET` request is not.  This means my intended

- `DELETE /things/21`
- `GET /things/`

becomes:

- `OPTIONS /things/21`
- `GET /things`
- `DELETE /things/21`

And the result of the `GET` includes object 21.

I want to avoid adding artificial delays; is there any other way to ensure the `DELETE` happens first?

(The requests are triggered from completely different components of my react app)

Edit:

I have a component `Things` which renders a summary list of things, and a component `Thing` which renders a page of detail.

`Thing` includes a `Delete` button, which fires a delete and navigates to `Things`.  By "fires a delete" I mean: triggers an ajax DELETE to `/things/21` and deletes thing 21 from my local redux store.

`Things` has a `componentWillMount` which triggers a `GET` to retrieve the list of available things, when they arrive my redux reducer adds them all to its store.

Edit: example:

Redux action creators

```
export const deleteThing = thingId => ({
  type: 'DELETE_THING',
  payload: thingId
});

export const retrieveThings = () => ({
  type: 'FETCH_THINGS'
});
```

"Reducer" responsible for API requests

```
export default store => next => action => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'DELETE_THING':
      return deleteObj(store.dispatch, action.type, `/things/{action.payload}`, action.payload);
    case 'FETCH_THINGS':
      return getObj(store.dispatch, action.type, '/things/');
  }
}

const getObj = (dispatch, action, url) => {
  return sendRequest(dispatch, () => fetch(url)
    .then(processResponse(dispatch, action))
    .catch(handleError(dispatch, action))
  );
};

const deleteObj = (dispatch, action, url, payload) => {
  return sendRequest(dispatch, () => fetch(url, {
      method: 'DELETE',
      headers
    })
    .then(results => {
      if (results.status >= 400) return handleError(dispatch, action)(results);

      // DELETE doesn't return anything but reducers want to know what was deleted, so pass the payload
      return dispatch({
        type: `${action}_SUCCESS`,
        payload
      });
    }) 
    .catch(handleError(dispatch, action))
  );
}

// Wraps a fetch request, triggering redux events on send/receive (regardless of outcome)
const sendRequest = (dispatch, fn) => {
  dispatch({type: 'SENDING_REQUEST'});
  const always = () => dispatch({type: 'RECEIVED_RESPONSE'});
  return fn().then(always, always);
}
```

Reducer/store for `Thing`s

```
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  case 'DELETE_THING_SUCCESS': 
    return state.deleteIn(['byId'], action.payload);
}
```

React Components

```
class Thing {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{props.thing.id}</h1>
        <button onClick={this.props.deleteThing}>Delete</button>
      </div>
    );
  }

  deleteThing () {
    this.props.triggerActionToSend
    // Pretend this is `connect`ed to a redux store
    this.props.deleteThing(this.props.id);

    // AJAX to delete from server
    fetch({
      url: '/thing/' + this.props.id,
      method: 'delete'
    });

    // Redirect to main list
    this.props.navigate('/things/');
  }
}

// Pretend this is a `connect`ed component that receives a `things` prop from a redux store
class Things {
  componentWillMount () {
    this.props.retrieveThings();
  }
  
  render () {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.props.things.map(x => <li>x.id</li>)}
      </ul>
    );
  }
);

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <Route path="/things" component={Things} />
    <Route path="/thing/:thingId" component={Thing} />
  </div>
);
```

Comment: your issue isn't because of the OPTIONS preflight, it's because you don't understand asynchronism - but without a lick of code, it's just a gut feeling

Comment: Don't even make the second request until first one completes. If you call them in succession there is no guarantee of completion order or even order they arrive at server

Comment: @JaromandaX Please see edit.  I understand async fine and realise I shouldn't rely on request ordering; however, I don't see how a data store can maintain integrity with this kind of async activity.

Comment: Well, it's not the preflight that is the problem. The code you haven't shown clearly does not guarantee the order of the requests anyway - but then as you've shown no code, it's still just a gut feeling

Comment: @JaromandaX Hold up I'll throw together an example

Comment: So you need to do the navigation after the delete operation is done. Only way you can ensure that an asynchronous operation is done is to wait for it to finish.

Comment: @JaromandaX added code example.

Comment: Using Promises FTW

Comment: Are you unable to delete your question?  Why edit and ask to ignore?

Comment: @zero298 correct.  That, and the incredibly hostile nature of SO in general.

Answer (score 0):

Change your navigation call to wait for `fetch` promise to resolve. Should probably do same with deleting from local store but that isn't the issue at hand

```
// AJAX to delete from server
fetch({
  url: '/thing/' + this.props.id,
  method: 'delete'
}).then(_=> this.props.navigate('/things/'));
```

Comment: This is the only way to do it. There's no guarantee the `DELETE` will hit the server before the `GET`.

Comment: The problem is the fetch doesn't happen directly in the component; the component calls an action creator, which asynchronously triggers the fetch at the same time as dispatching the action which the reducer uses to delete the object ...

Comment: I have many reducers; one is responsible for handling all API calls, and another stores data of this type.  They both "do" something with the `action.type` triggered by the component when the Delete button is clicked.

Comment: Furthermore, if the fetch is happening outside the component then your example needs to reflect that. Help us help you.

Comment: @charlietfl yes it does, it's a pattern known as "optimistic updates".

Comment: @AlexMcMillan that's fine if it's wired up that way. See a lot of people not think about it nd get caught wondering what to do when request fails